# Dropdown does not work properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, safari

Hello every one recently i've written a web page (skeleton) however i stuck on small problem , my button menu does not work properly in safari (i used bootstrap so button is appeared when width less then 768px) , thus as i click a button nothing is appeared but as soon as i move my mouse out of the web page menu is appearing .
Button has to drop down menu on the whole page (it works perfectly in Google chrome and Firefox)

JavaScript

```
function drop(){
    document.getElementById("myDrop").classList.toggle("show");
    document.getElementById("head1").classList.toggle("disableHeaderAndSection");
    document.getElementById("section1").classList.toggle("disableHeaderAndSection");
}
```

CSS

```
.drop-content{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    top:50px;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    display:none;   
    background:white;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    padding:20px;
        border-radius:10px;}
.show {
    display:block;


}
```

HTML

```
<div id="outdrop">

                    <div class="drop-content" id="myDrop">
                        <h3>Menu</h3>
                        <p>menu part 1</p>
                        <p>menu part 2</p>
                        <p>menu part 3</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Please help me solve this problem (i've put my skeleton in a free hosting) page- bloggd.rf.gd

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, *Code*

Comment: Post code with the question in order to make us able to help you with your code..!

Comment: I tried this on Safari PC and it works.  Are you using Mac, Mobile?

Comment: yes i was trying on apple-Mobile and mac

Comment: And on android with browser Dolphin

Comment: but the button does not work properly